# node-midi multiple inputs for multiple applications simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, midi

I'm working on [node-midi](https://github.com/justinlatimer/node-midi), a node.js wrapper for the RtMidi C++ library that provides realtime MIDI I/O, and its simplified wrapper [node-easymidi](https://github.com/dinchak/node-easymidi).

The library is working great, but one thing, I wanted to read the midi piano keyboard input from not only the easymidi, but also from an other application, FL studio, to play the midi input sounds. If I try to connect to easymidi while FL studio, I get an error `MidiInWinMM::initialize: no MIDI input devices currently available.`. So I needed to exit FL studio before running the node app.

So, how can I modify the code to work with multiple applications aside from the node app? Or I need to install other libraries or change Windows settings? I read google, stackoverflow, github issue, but couldn't find a solution by myself. So I want your help here. Thank you.

Here's the code.

```js
var easymidi = require('easymidi');

var inputs = easymidi.getInputs();
var outputs = easymidi.getOutputs();
console.log(inputs, outputs ) ;
// [ 'CASIO USB-MIDI 0' ] [ 'Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth 0', 'CASIO USB-MIDI 1' ]

var input = new easymidi.Input('CASIO USB-MIDI 0');

input.on('noteon', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg ) ;
});
input.on('noteoff', function (msg) {
  console.log(msg ) ;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MIDI instruments cannot be shared in Windows.
If the port is used by one application, another application cannot connect to it.